# Why does fullcalendar give the error that it does not provide an export called 'default'?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, asset-pipeline, stimulusjs

I am trying to use the fullcalenar library through stimulusjs to display the calendar in a rails app, without a webpacker.
To start I just want to show the calendar, without complexity, as in the documentation, and the controller I am trying to do looks like this:

```js
import FullCalendar from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@5.10.0/main.global.min.js'

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["calendar"]
  connect() {

    this.init()
  }

  init() {

    this.calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(this.calendarTarget, {
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    })

    this.calendar.render()
  }

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.0/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div data-controller="fullcalendar">
  <div data-target="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

the error that it throws and that I do not understand is the following:

`Failed to autoload controller: fullcalendar SyntaxError: The requested module 'blob:http://localhost:3000/1c3e6673-aecc-4144-b5d6-471fb03b5e0f' does not provide an export named 'default'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FullCalendar has two primary installation methods. You're using the one from [this documentation page](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals), which does not export ES6 modules. It's more like the old (pre-Gulp/Webpack) way of importing global variables.

If you want to `import` inside your Stimulus controllers, you'll either need to use Webpack or something importmaps, just like [the other FullCalendar installation page says](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-es6).

If you want something basic, I'd recommend importmaps (https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails). It requires very little configuration compared to Webpack, and will allow what you're trying to do.